# ROS topic communication between robots?

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand how ROS topics work, then communication between two robots running ROS via topics should be relatively straightforward.  Am I correct, and if so can you point me to a helpful resource on the matter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10064/ros-topic-communication-between-robots?/) by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2011-05-25

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-26**:
Please search ROS answers before asking questions, this is a duplicate. http://answers.ros.org/questions/?query=multimaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked a very similar question here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/103/how-can-multiple-robots-communicate-using-ros

Essentially, there is no "official", comprehensive solution to this problem available so far, but there are some packages available that might (or might not) solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2